Nitric acid Reaction Products
Why does concentrated nitric acid gives primarily NO2, while dilute nitric acid gives NO?
My explanation is that, concentrated HNO3 exist mainly as molecular HNO3, while dilute HNO3 exist as H+ and NO3-.  HNO3 are stronger oxidizers than NO3-,thus NO reacts with HNO3 forming NO2.
Is this correct? I couldnt find any paper on this topic.
Thanks for your help

This question is similar to: How does copper reduce dilute nitric acid to nitric oxide and concentrated nitric acid to nitrogen dioxide?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97090/which-is-a-better-oxidising-agent-concentrated-nitric-acid-or-dilute-nitric-aci
